# how to find the minimum value of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x\cos(x)}$

Tags: calculus

how to find the minimum value of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x\cos(x)}$? $x\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$

My try:
differential $f$:
$$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{x\sin(x)-\cos(x)}{x^2\cos^2(x)}=0$$
then $x\tan(x)=1$. How to find the value of $x$?

I appreciate also other methods to find the minimum of $f(x)$.

Comment: I cant seem to see how there can be a closed form solution to this. Try it out in wolfram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an analytic solution, but here's how you'd find the solution numerically in $Mathematica$:

```
{#, NMinimize[
    {1/(x*Cos[x]), 0 < x < Pi/2},
    x,
    Method -> #
    ]} & /@ {"NelderMead", "DifferentialEvolution", "SimulatedAnnealing", "RandomSearch"}
```

The output is

```
{{"NelderMead", {1.78223, {x -> 0.860334}}},
 {"DifferentialEvolution", {1.78223, {x -> 0.860334}}},
 {"SimulatedAnnealing", {1.78223, {x -> 0.860334}}},
 {"RandomSearch", {1.78223, {x -> 0.860334}}}}
```

That is, all of the minimization methods found the same solution. For those unfamiliar with the $Mathematica$ language but wishing to manipulate the code, a simplified example is

```
NMinimize[{1/(x*Cos[x]), 0 < x < Pi/2}, x, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

which outputs

```
{1.78223, {x -> 0.860334}}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no closed solution for what you are trying to calculate. The minimum value can be calculated numerically, but you cannot get a "nice looking" solution, unfortunatelly.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "closed solution"? I don't understand this term.

Comment: A closed solution would mean that it is expressed by some function. For example, the solution to $e^x = 10$ is $x=\ln 10$ ant this is a closed solution. For the equation $x\tan x = 1$, no such formula exists.

Answer (score 1):

Let us say that the function goes through an extremum for the value $a$ which is the solution of $a \tan(a)=1$. At this point, the value of the function is then $\sec (a) \tan (a)$.

Now, the problem is to solve, using numerical methods, the equation $f(x)=x \tan(x)-1=0$. A classical method is Newton provided a reasonable starting point. By inspection, you would see that the function is negative at $\frac {\pi}{4}$ and positive at $\frac {\pi}{3}$. for this function Newton iterates will be given by $$\frac{2 x^2+\cos (2 x)+1}{2 x+\sin (2 x)}$$ Starting iterations at $x=\frac {\pi}{4}$, Newton iterates will successively be $0.868875$, $0.860441$, $0.860334$ which is the final solution.

So the value of the function at the extremum is $\sec (0.860334) \tan (0.860334)=1.78223$.

Answer (score 0):

Best bet would be to try some Taylor polynomial approximation and then find the roots of the corresponding polynomial.